# If the result of a select query is empty (no rows) what does the variable hold?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Here is an example code:

```
$db = connect_db();

$result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");
$result->execute();
$result = $result->fetchAll();
```

If my users table was empty there would be no rows returned, so what does $result hold?

If I reference it like this:

```
if(!(isset($result))) print "no users";
```

will it work?

Thanks for any answers!

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: Run `SELECT * FROM users WHERE 0`, then `var_dump($result)` and find out.

Comment: a query which has no results is STILL a valid result - you'll get a result handle, but the fetchall will return an empty array.

Comment: @jh314, because the table is not empty and the database is not mine to change. I wanted a quick answer to a problem not a response from someone trying to make me look like a fool.

Thanks to everyone else who tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs for [`fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php):

> **An empty array** is returned if there are zero results to fetch, or FALSE on failure.

So, no, `isset()` will not work as the variable is set with an empty array. You should use [`empty()`](http://php.net/empty) or [`count()`](http://php.net/count) instead. Or, better yet, one of the PDO methods like [`rowCount()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) (if your db supports this).

**Note:** The docs are your friend.